# C - Integer array issue

Tags: c, arrays

I'm recently new to the site and figured I'd try my hand at asking a question. I'm currently working on a C program (for reference I'm using a gcc compiler and PuTTy to write and compile my program). I'm a first year computer science student and I'm having an issue with a segment of my code. I'll post the relevant parts here.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int classIDs[24];
    int userEnteredClassID;
    int classCounter=0;

    int i;

    /*Initializing the class array to 25 elements with a '0' in each.*/
    printf("\nCurrent class ID numbers; empty spaces in the array are signaled by a '0'\n");
    for(i=0;i<25;i++)
    {
            classIDs[i]=0;
            printf("%d  ", classIDs[i]);
    }


    printf("\n\nPlease enter a class ID number:\n");

    /*Checking if they entered an integer value period.*/
    if(scanf("%d",&userEnteredClassID)!=1)
    {
            printf("\nYou have entered a class ID that is not an integer value.\n\n");
    }

    /*Checking if they entered a negative integer value.*/
    else if(userEnteredClassID<0)
    {
            printf("\nYou have entered an invalid integer for a class ID (negative).\n\n");
    }

    /*A valid integer was entered.*/
    else
    {
            /*Now need to check if the class has been entered before.*/
            int j;

            for(j=0; j<25; j++)
            {
                    /*Checks if user has entered that class ID before.*/
                    if(classIDs[j]==userEnteredClassID)
                    {
                            printf("\nYou've already entered that class ID!\n");
                            userEnteredClassID=0;
                            break;
                    }

                    /*If the current element doesn't equal the class ID entered, keep traversing the array.*/
                    if(classIDs[j]!=userEnteredClassID)
                    {
                            continue;
                    }

                    /*Entire loop was traversed and there weren't any duplicate class IDs, so a new class will be added to array.*/
                    classIDs[classCounter]=userEnteredClassID;
                    classCounter+=1;

            }

            /*Printinf class ID array.*/
            int k;
            printf("\nComplete list of class IDs; remember empty spaces are represented by '0'\n");
            for(k=0; k<25; k++)
            {
                    printf("%d  ", classIDs[k]);
            }

            printf("\n\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to have an integer array of class IDs of size 25 initialized with all elements being 0 (for the time being). Then, I will have the user enter an integer value. If the user enters a character of some kind in the input, the program ends.

If the user enters a negative integer, the program ends. Where I'm having the issue is in my third block after those too checks happen. At this point, I want the program to recognize that the input is in fact an integer and it is a positive value. I hope to use this program with multiple user inputs, so this next bit of code checks if the user already inputted the ID they are requesting.

My issue is that no matter what positive integer value I input while practicing this code, the program returns that the class ID has already been entered. I've done my best to troubleshoot the program myself to figure out what I've done wrong, but I've spent way too much time staring at this to make any headway. If anyone could shed light on this problem that would be fantastic. I hope I've been descriptive enough with my problem, and if something is still unclear I'll elaborate further if needed.

Thank you for taking the time to look at my question, cheers!

**Added amendment to program**
I have now change the initial declaration for the classIDs array to classIDs[25] and my thir block of code looks like this:

```
 /*A valid integer was entered.*/
    else
    {
            /*Now need to check if the class has been entered before.*/
            int j;

            for(j=0; j<25; j++)
            {
                    /*Checks if user has entered that class ID before.*/
                    if(classIDs[j]==userEnteredClassID)
                    {
                            printf("\nYou've already entered that class ID!\n");
                            userEnteredClassID=0;
                            break;
                    }

                    /*If the current element doesn't equal the class ID entered, keep traversing the array.*/
                    else if(classIDs[j]!=userEnteredClassID && j<=23)
                    {
                            continue;
                    }

                    /*Entire loop was traversed and there weren't any duplicate class IDs, so a new class will be added to array.*/
                    else
                    {
                            classIDs[classCounter]=userEnteredClassID;
                            classCounter+=1;

                            /*Printinf class ID array.*/
                            int k;
                            printf("\nComplete list of class IDs; remember empty spaces are represented by '0'\n");
                            for(k=0; k<25; k++)
                            {
                                    printf("%d  ", classIDs[k]);
                            }

                            printf("\n\n");
                    }
            }
    }
```

Comment: If you want an array of size 25, you need to make an array of size 25, not 24.

Comment: To expand on Kerrek's comment, when _declaring_ an array, you need to specify the _number_ of elements. However, when _accessing_ elements in an array, you need to specify the _0-based index_. So, the index of the last element will always be one less than the number of elements in that array.

Comment: if(classIDs[j]!=userEnteredClassID)  then you **continue** here, you will never have a chance to put the input id into you array.

Comment: Oh goodness, isn't that just a little embarrassing... Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the obvious [24] fix, the code after "/*Entire loop was traversed...*/" will never be executed. You're trying to do this:

```
for (...) {
    if (match) {
        break;
    }
    if (!match) {
        continue;
    }
    /* You will never get here! */
    gotit();
 }
```

What you really want is something like this:

```
found = 0;
for (...) {
    if (match) {
        found = 1;
        break;
    }
}
if (!found) {
    gotit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tinkered with the code a bit and have amended the last block that contains the break and continue based on some of the advice you gave. I did a different spin on it though due to my needing to read multiple elements and multiple values (eventually).

Answer (score 0):

```
int classIDs[24];
int userEnteredClassID;

j = 24;
if(classIDs[j]==userEnteredClassID)
```

The last line above accesses memory that is not covered by the array `classIDs`. It's a bit undefined behavior because the compiler can place the local variables in any order (and any alignment) on the stack. But in your case you don't access classIDs[24] but the next variable (`userEnteredClassID`). Use a sensible size of your array.

Comment: Thanks for the catch on the size 24; that was just a really stupid mistake by me.